# Display images with v-for in Vue/Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, src, v-for

I'm trying to display some images side by side in columns using this methodology:

```
<v-row>
  <v-col v-for="(n, i) in footerLogos" :key="i">
    <v-img :src="`${n}`"></v-img>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

The array:

```
footerLogos: [
        "@/assets/inc5000.jpg",
        "@/assets/inc-honor-roll.jpg",
        "@/assets/asa.jpg",
        "@/assets/soaringeagle.jpg",
        "@/assets/inahu.jpg",
        "@/assets/nahu-eagle.jpg",
        "@/assets/inc5000.jpg"
      ]
```

To me this SHOULD work but it doesn't.  What am I missing?  Or is there a better/simpler way to do it?
I've tried a few variations such as the paths being "@assets/...." versus "@/assets/..." but nothing seems to work.  Surely I'm missing something simple.  Please help! :)

I'm using Vue, Vuetify and Nuxt

Comment: no, this should not work. Something like `:src="require('n')"` should. There are enough resources for this approach in internet

Answer (score 3):

If you need import some image from your file system, first you need import this file with a require function.
Please, take a look in the code below...

```
footerLogos: [
        require('~/assets/inc5000.jpg'),
        require('~/assets/inc-honor-roll.jpg'),
        require('~/assets//assets/asa.jpg'),
        require('~/assets/soaringeagle.jpg'),
        require('~/assets/inahu.jpg'),
        require('~/assets/nahu-eagle.jpg'),
        require('~/assets/inc5000.jpg')
      ]
```

However, if you will use a imagem from some URL, some thing like (https://example.com/img01.png) you don't need use require, just use a correctly path and this will work propertly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<v-row>
  <v-col v-for="(n, i) in footerLogos" :key="i">
    <v-img :src="require(`${n}`)"></v-img>
  </v-col>
</v-row>

footerLogos: [
        "./assets/inc5000.jpg",
        "./assets/inc-honor-roll.jpg",
        "./assets/asa.jpg",
        "./assets/soaringeagle.jpg",
        "./assets/inahu.jpg",
        "./assets/nahu-eagle.jpg",
        "./assets/inc5000.jpg"
      ]
```

Did'nt work for me with the @

Comment: @HenriqueVanKlaveren you are right, i fixed it, i added the require on the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use require if you are using Vite

Someone else found this which worked for me

For the Vite environment, the solution is to use new URL('[path_to_image]', import.meta.url).href

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75655533)